# How To remove Backslash in propel query in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, oracle11g

What I need:

- I need to remove `\` from string, therefore It's not working in propel orm.
- we are using Symfony 1.2 I have used: `stripslashes ($surname);` and `str_replace('/\\\\/', '', $str)`
- but both of them don"t work in Symfony propel query I don't know why.

Symfony code:

```
 $surname='H-O'nel';
 if ($email == null)
  throw Exception("Invalid Parameters.");
echo $surname;
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin(EmailAddressesPeer::PERSON_ID,  PersonsPeer::PERSON_ID);
$c->add(EmailAddressesPeer::EMAIL_ADDRESS,$email, Criteria::EQUAL);
$c->add(PersonsPeer::SURNAME,$surname, Criteria::EQUAL);
$c->add(EmailAddressesPeer::END_DATE, null, Criteria::ISNULL);
print_r(EmailAddressesPeer::doSelectOne($c));
print_r($c->toString());
var_dump(EmailAddressesPeer::doSelectOne($c));
```

Query:

```
Criteria: SQL (may not be complete): SELECT FROM email_addresses, persons WHERE email_addresses.EMAIL_ADDRESS=:p1 AND persons.SURNAME=:p2 AND email_addresses.END_DATE IS NULL AND email_addresses.PERSON_ID=persons.PERSON_ID Params: email_addresses.EMAIL_ADDRESS => 'abc@abc.com', persons.SURNAME =>'H-O'nel'
```

Output: `null` for query results.

Problem:

- when I'm sending sending value from textbox that corrects as already mentioned $surname to some string.
- but when sending values in propel query its appending '\' in string.
- give `null` results.
- help in this issue I have wasted 3 to 4 hours in this issue but could not solved it.

  ```
   update query : update persons set surname='Om''Dram' where person_id='****'
  ```
- i think issue in string H-O'nel when its appended in where clause its results H-O\'nel which is wrong

array

Array ( [0] => H [1] => O'neill )